# Push files in a input of type file

Tags: javascript

This is difficult to explain.

What I would want is to know if it's possible to push "file objects" into a INPUT[type="file"], and how can i do it.

Instead of clicking the "browse files" button, I would like to "push" the objects from other input file outside an iframe.

I mean, is possible to "pass" what an input file received to another input file inside a frame ?

Comment: What is a "file object"? For security reasons JavaScript can not set a file path in the input.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT Dec 2020 : This answer is outdated. As per the comment by @Markus1980Wien

> As of 2020 this is not true anymore. You can get the fileData using
> Drag&Drop and move the received file into an input type="file" object.
> This will also display the file-name, as if the file was selected by
> clicking the "browse" button of the file-input.

You can't do that. Browsers do not not allow you to set the value of a file input box due to security restrictions

Comment: You still can't. The value in the input field can't be changed via JS

Comment: Do you want to do this so you can upload files without refreshing the page?

Comment: As of 2020 this is not true anymore.
You can get the fileData using Drag&Drop and move the received file into an input type="file" object. This will also display the file-name, as if the file was selected by clicking the "browse" button of the file-input.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer. It's almost a decade old now.